# Decompiled not obfused apk contains errors in java code

Tags: java, android

I used [android app decompiler](http://www.javadecompilers.com/apk) to decompile random app. It seems that app is not obfuscated - even variable names are preserved. The thing is with java code. Sometimes I am getting an error. That's the sample:

```
private long compressAndFormat(byte[] token data) {
        long result = 0;
        int i = 0;
        while (true) {
            try {
                if (i >= this.ipb.length) {
                    return result >> 1;
                }
                int bit;
                while (bit >= 0) {
                    byte mask = (byte) (1 << bit);
                    if ((this.ipb[i] & mask) != 0) {
                        if ((tokenData[i] & mask) != 0) {
                            result |= 1;
                        }
                        result <<= 1;
                    }
                    bit--;
                }
                i++;
            } finally {
                result = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

In this scenario I am getting error `Variable 'bit' might not have been initialized`. Why does that happen? This app was written in an older version of java, where you could use variables without initialization, or there is something wrong with decompiler?

Comment: this happens because 'Variable 'bit' might not have been initialized'. int bit; -> just initialize it to a basic value

Comment: @Stultuske I know. I am wondering why does that happen. Why there is `bit`, but not `bit = 0`.